# How do I integrate abook with a carddav server?

Tags: synchronization, addressbook, mutt, carddav

I'm running Nextcloud, and my contacts are synced to my laptop with `vdirsyncer`, which leaves me with a directory full of `.vcf` files. I'd like to abook to be able to read and edit those but I'm not quite sure how to make that happen.

Is that even possible? Or am I just dreaming?

Comment: I think this might be more suitable for ServerFault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

abook does not generally know how to read or write vcf.

It does have vcf import and export functions, and with a lot of time on your hands (and good backups) you could exploit that somehow to synchronize abook's database with your `.vcf`-directory. The problem is that abook's import/export functions are not that good. Also abook's import will drop data it can't handle (e.g. contact photo) which is not very useful.

There are other addressbooks specifically made to work with `vdirsyncer`, most notably [khard](https://github.com/scheibler/khard).

--

Source: I am the author of vdirsyncer (not the author of khard though).